# nested switch : why does the second switch command not accept an input?

Tags: c, nested, switch-statement, dev-c++

i'm new to c programming and as i was going through my assignments for my c language course, i came upon a problem...

```
int main() {
char one, ona, onb;

/*code for choices (a), (b), and (c) here*/
scanf ("%c", &one);

switch (one) {
    case 'a':
        /*code for choices (d), and (e) here*/
        scanf ("%c", &ona);

        switch (ona) {
            case 'd':
                printf ("end");
                break;
            case 'e':
                printf ("continue");
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 'b':
        /*code for case 'b' here*/
        break;

    case 'c':
        /*code for case 'c' here*/
        break;
}

system ("pause > nul");
getch ();
return 0;
}
```

my nested switch commands (the ones under ona and onb) don't work when i compile & run my console application?

i've checked all the break; commands and they're all there? is there something i am missing / doing wrong?

i have tried to read other similar questions regarding nested switch, however, i have not found one that addresses my problem...

i use system ("pasue > nul") after multiple printf statments if that helps find an answer? (also, i am using dev-c++ as it was the recommended application our professor told us to use)

i am hoping someone might be able to find what i have coded wrongly;; thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: What does 'isn't working' mean?

Comment: The problem is not your code but your inputs. Test with "ad" (for example) it will work.

Comment: well, when i run the program and get to the part where the switch(ona) is supposed to be working, it doesn't, and it goes straight to the last part of the code > printf("\n\n"); (...) return 0; } :(

Comment: "My code isn't working" is not a **specific** problem statement. Take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: aah, i do apologize! i'll be editing the title then, and thank you for letting me know! @Olaf :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` will match any character, including a newline.  After the first `scanf`, the character you enter is placed in `one` and a newline is left in the input buffer.  The next `scanf` picks up the newline that was left in the buffer, and you don't get prompted for anything as a result.

This is why adding an extra `scanf` seemed to fix your problem.

When using `%c`, you should put a space before it in the pattern.  The space will match and discard any newlines.

So change these:

```
scanf ("%c", &one);
...
scanf ("%c", &ona);
...
scanf ("%c", &onb);
```

To these:

```
scanf (" %c", &one);
...
scanf (" %c", &ona);
...
scanf (" %c", &onb);
```

It's also important to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that the expected number of patterns were matched, and put in error handling when that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably typing something like "a <enter> d", causing your second `scanf` to read the enter key. If you write code to read characters, you have to enter characters. If you're going to enter lines, write code to read lines.

Comment: hello! i'm so sorry for troubling you, but how might i be able to avoid having to <enter> after inputting "a" as the switch i've coded does not automatically execute after i type "a" in?

thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @fujisaki Write code that does what you actually want. If you want to read *lines*, then write code that reads lines. Or perhaps you should write a function that reads a character but ignores newlines. Code what you want.

Comment: i've added another `scanf` before the `scanf ("%c", &ona);` and `switch(ona)` finally ran! there's probably a better way to fix my problem though, haha

thank you so very much for answering!! i'm very grateful!!